# How can this equation with logarithms not be solved?

Tags: equation-solving

```
Reduce[{Log[a, b] + Log[b, a] == 5/2, a^b == b^a, a > 0, b > 0, 
  t == a/b}, t, {a, b}]
```

Always showing no results while running

Comment: @BobHanlon I believe `Reduce` does accept elimination variables. See warning given by `Reduce[{x^2 - y^2 == a, x y == a}, {x, y}, a]`. Use `{a}` to avoid the warning message.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - Yes, I was mistaken

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `Reals`.

```
Reduce[{Log[a, b] + Log[b, a] == 5/2, a^b == b^a, a > 0, b > 0, 
  t == a/b}, t, {a, b},Reals]
```

> `t==1/2 ||t==2`